# How to install a specific R version in ubuntu

Tags: r

I need to install two versions of R in Ubuntu (i.e., versions 3.5 and 4).
How can i do this in Ubuntu ?

I think that previous versions are available [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to build from source. Using this post as guideline: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-to-compile-and-install-programs-from-source

1. Download the tar.gz for specific version
2. Extract using `tar zxvf myapp.tar.gz`
3. cd into the directory by step 2
4. run `./configure && make && sudo make install`

Comment: I had found another possibility : https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/02/installing-r-on-ubuntu/

Comment: You can also obtain already compiled binaries of R from RStudio: https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/

Comment: As an aside the above will NOT work for multiple versions either as the second `make install` will overwrite the first.  You need additional arguments to `configure` to distinguish versions and/or installation paths.

Comment: I didn't understand the step 3 : what this the directory to use for cd command ?

Comment: When you expand a source archive (ending in a file `*.tar.gz`) it creates a directory. The `cd` command can then change into that directory. If all that is new to you then compiling from source as suggested by this answer will have other challenges for you.

Comment: for example `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/oldR` will install everything into a subdirectory (rather than the default `/usr/local`)

Answer (score 3):

You *cannot* install multiple binary (Debian or Ubuntu) packages *at the same time*.  You can (if their depends are verified) install individual binary packages, at at a time. Debian even has a [snapshot archive](https://snapshot.debian.org) but I am unsure about Ubuntu.

What you *can do very easily* is access different R versions via Docker *at the same time*:

```
$ alias dkrr    # useful alias used below
alias dkrr='docker run --rm -ti -u1000:1000 -v$(pwd):/work -w /work'
$ for v in 3.3.3 3.4.4 3.5.3 3.6.3 4.0.5 4.1.0; \  # indented for display
        do dkrr r-base:${v} Rscript --version; done
R scripting front-end version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
R scripting front-end version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
R scripting front-end version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
R scripting front-end version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
R scripting front-end version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
R scripting front-end version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
$
```

That just run `Rscript`, you can of course also access `R` in the same containers.

I maintain that container as part of the Rocker Project (and I look after the Debian package too).  There is a good mailing list available for these questions: r-sig-debian.

*Edit:* For kicks, and address the comment "it ain't working" here is an animated gif from my box showing that (and how) it does.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for this question sir but where should i run this ( in R studio or ubuntu terminal ) ?

Comment: In a regular bash shell, so 'terminal' either a Gnome Terminal or the RStudio terminal or ....  You cannot point (regular) RStudio at multiple binaries, the commercial RStudio Pro can.  You can also build multiple containers each with RStudio and a different R version but that requires knowing a little about containers.

Comment: The loop isn't working , it gives many syntax errors . I tried to copy it in a separate text file.sh then i runned the code from terminal without success

Comment: Slowly. It was a) a literal copy and paste so it worked here but b) you must remove the one trailing backslash I inserted for display purposes and c) you must (of course) have the corresponding Docker images.  Do `docker images | grep ^r-base` to check which you have.  Oh, and you need to define the alias and/or expand the command by hand.

Comment: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Comment: You can use StackOverflow to learn how to setup Docker; that is a distinct and new question. If you don't have it working then this too may not be a solution for you.

Comment: Ok , i will do a search. Thank you a lot for your help :)   !