# How to list the installed R version?

Tags: r

Good afternoon ,

I tried to install a number of R versions in ubuntu terminal using a suggested shell solution in my previous question : [how-to-install-a-specific-r-version-in-ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672750/how-to-install-a-specific-r-version-in-ubuntu)

However , I cannot see the installed R versions under Rstudio : Tools -> global options :

[image]

I'm unable to check if i installed the R versions properly !

Thank you for help !

Comment: Enter `R.version.string` into R.

Comment: You can also simply type `version` in the console. Note that only one version is installed in linux. Any upgrade replaces the previous version. That is different from, e.g., windows, where you can have several different `R` versions installed on the same system.

Comment: I'm feeling like using R in linux isn't a good choice since i can't use several versions at same time

Comment: (1) Would someone include one of these comments as an answer? (2) @RHertel, What do you mean you can't install several versions of R on the same system in Linux? Why not? (Are you specifically talking about installing from pre-compiled `.deb`/`.rpm`?) (The whole previous [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672750/how-to-install-a-specific-r-version-in-ubuntu) goes over how you can install multiple versions ...

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, I am talking about the usual installation via pre-compiled packages. I am aware that different versions can be used in Docker (Dirk Eddelbuettel has shown this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67673360/) ), but it is not how a standard R user would normally proceed.

Comment: That's fine. I just wanted to point out that the OP might have misunderstood your comment (based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675690/how-to-list-the-installed-r-version?noredirect=1#comment119619977_67675690))

Comment: @TouMou You keep repeating this (over mulitple questions), it remains untrue. Fundamentallym _only one command in your `$PATH` can be named `R` at the same time_ but that does not stop one from having multiple _differently named `R-3.5`, `R-3.6`, ... and so on, just how I showed you that Docker can do that for you to.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel , i had installed the versions using your shell script. However the Rstudio IDE isn't able to detect the new installed version

Comment: Years ago I answered a question about "how to install multiple versions of an R package" and at a very fundamental level _it is the same with R itself_.  They simply have to sit 'next to each other'.  What I said in a comment to your first (of several near identical) question(s) remains true: The _premade_ package does not accomodate it.  By hand, you can do whatever.  These facts will not change even if you ask the same question N more times, slightly reworded.

Comment: If "all you want" is RStudio with a drop-down for multiple versions, consider just paying for RStudio Cloud where this will be provided to you as a service.

Comment: I will just use windows 7 instead , it's very simple to install multiple R versions there !

Comment: So it is in Ubuntu. But if you're more at ease with Windows 7 then by all means use that.  For example, many of us keep `R` (the current version, often from a binary) as well as `RD` (shortcut for R-devel).  Clearly more than one version, clearly on one system, clearly doable.  Repeat for fixed R versions if you want those.